# GNOME Shell: pressing the Super key does not work

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with GNOME 3.2 and completely loving it. On one computer it works like a charm, but on another computer the <kbd>Super</kbd> does not show the Activities overview. Mousing over the top-left corner does bring up the overview, so I am not totally blocked, but I am really missing being able to just press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to get there.

In *System Settings* → *Keyboard* there is an option to change the shortcut for *Show the activities overview*, but I can't set it to <kbd>Super</kbd> (I guess because it is considered to be a modifier-key):

[image: Screenshot showing Show the activities overview shortcut]

Does anybody have a clue how I could fix this?

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Same - experiencing this with 20.04

Comment: Same here on Ubuntu 20.04 it is pretty annoying. It works with En keyboard layout but it does not work with Pt-Br layout.

Comment: @leoheck - I confirm, this was a great input! I often switch between Swiss-German and en layout, and hadn't realized that the super key never works in German, while it does in en!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In older Ubuntu versions, go to **System Settings → Keyboard Layout → Layouts** and then choose **Options**.

In newer Ubuntu versions, install Tweaks (`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`) and open it, then **Keyboard & Mouse** and then choose **Additional Layout Options**. There is an option for the **Alt/Win key behaviour** and there I had the option selected **Meta is mapped to Win**.

[image: Additional Layout Options]

Deselecting that option, and choosing **Alt and meta are on Alt** fixes it for me. At least the <kbd>Super</kbd>  button is working again to access the **Activities**. Not quite sure what the impact of this choice is.

Comment: Hm that did the trick for me too! However, I don't understand the description of the option. One might think that ticking the option will make the Win key work as an Alt key.

Comment: I had a similar problem with Debian 9.2, and this helped. In `gnome-tweak-tool`, under `Typing` > `Alt/Win key behaviour` I just chose some random option and afterwards set it to `Disabled` again (which was the default). It then worked again.

Comment: It did not work for me.

Comment: @Flimm not really sure why you edited my answer like you did? Would such a change not warrant a new answer? My answer is now outdated obviously --2011 and I have moved to mac osx sinc 2012

Comment: @nathanvda I made the answer up-to-date. The dialog is the same, you just need to go through a different set of menus to find it. If you think the answer is so out-of-date that it can't be edited to be made useful, feel free to delete your answer. (Stack Exchange doesn't have good solutions for information that gets out-of-date.)

Comment: The answer is not out of date, it solved this problem for me on `20.04`, (I had `gnome-tweaks` already installed). It is an unexpected answer too, I am very glad you went all the way to find it yourself.

Comment: For me, I needed "Alt is swapped with Win"

Comment: For me, I disabled the default "Left Win" in the section "Switching to another layout". Do not ask me why ...

Answer (score 38):

Okay. You might have locked your <kbd>Super</kbd> button. Try to unlock it on your keyboard. It usually has two icons, a window key and a lock.

In my case, I have unlocked the <kbd>Super</kbd> button by pressing <kbd>Right Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or, in another keyboard, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Window</kbd>.

Since then, everything works perfectly.

Comment: For me it was Fn + F2. Thank you so much!

Comment: On my keyboard it was Fn + F6. The F6 key is labeled "G/PC", which wasn't very descriptive.

Comment: TY fn + f2 or me also. Why is that even an option lol

Comment: mine was function f2 on illegear raven

Comment: On my alienware M15 R4 it was Fn + F6. The F6 key doesn't have any label though!

Comment: `fn + F1` did it for me. Didn't even know this was a thing. Thanks!

Comment: Fn + Super Key for my Monoprice

Comment: Fn+Right Win key to enable and Fn+Left Win key to disable for me.

Answer (score 2):

Under gnome 3.4.2.1, I had to use *Meta is mapped to Win*.
Now shortcuts with <kbd>Super</kbd> key work now.

Comment: It did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I figured it was because "Overview Shortcut" was mapped to "Left Super", but I was clicking on "Right Super".
Install `tweaks` and go to "Keyboard & Mouse" tab as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case you use a laptop stand with an additional keyboard unplugging re plugging the additional keyboard might fix the issue with the super/activity key.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome tweaks does not work for me. You can see the shortcuts from Settings > Keyboard > View and Customize Shortcuts, as the OP suggests.

Gnome developers apparently decided to map it to <Super + S> at some point. I can't change it back to Super either, but this at least tells you what it is mapped to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I did to resolve this problem was to:
`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

then `Keyboard & Mouse` -> Click on right super and on left super back again.

The left super now works as intended, without having to do nothing complicated.

I'd love to be able to also use both super keys for bringing overview, but this is good enough for me right now.

If somebody finds a solution similar to mine in simplicity, but that makes 2 super keys bring up overview, that would be lovely and I'd gladly edit/update my answer.