# Super Key does not invoke activities in Gnome Shell 3.8

Tags: gnome, 13.10

Pressing the *Super*  key does not launch the *Activities*, although the hot key to the top left corner to activate *Activities* do work. I tried following the link [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69648/gnome-shell-pressing-the-super-key-does-not-work) but the solution there does not work for me.

I am running Ubuntu 13.10, Gnome 3.8 Shell. I had a similar issue with Unity few days back but I resolved that via Unity plugin in ccsm.

Comment: Any help, anyone.. o.O

Comment: Resolved the issue myself using dconf editor.. :)

Comment: How did you do this with the dconf editor?

Comment: Go to org->gnome->mutter and then for the "overlay-key" put the value "Super_L" and its done!! Here Super_L is the left super key of the keyboard or the default windows key..

Answer (score 4):

Having the same problem I ended up here. Though it was Super Left in the dconf-editor, my super key was not working. Inspired by adiyaarun1's comment, I opened up *Tweak Tool—>Keyboard and Mouse*. If you change *Switch between overview and desktop* to **Super left** the problem should be solved as it was my case.

Comment: In my case, using the HHKB Pro 2 and having set my super key to be on the right side of the keyboard, I had to switch that to "Right super". Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!