# Super key not detected in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

It worked fine until I upgraded Ubuntu from 18.10 to 19.04. Now the <kbd>super</kbd> key is not detected and I can't set it as a custom shortcut and neither use it with default shortcuts. I can't find anything about <kbd>super</kbd> key behavior in settings.

Under **Settings > Region and Language > Input sources** the keys of the preview keyboard work fine but the <kbd>super</kbd> key, <kbd>fn</kbd> key and <kbd>menu</kbd> key, which are not recognized (not highlighted when pressed). I also tried changing to English as input source, but didn't solve the problem.

Is there something I'm missing?

**Info:**
GNOME Shell 3.32.0, Ubuntu 19.04, keyboard layout: Italian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem was "solved" by

1. enabling a random option **in gnome-tweak-tools > keyboard and mouse > additional layout options > Alt/Win key behavior**
2. closing the window
3. opening it again and set to **disabled** (which was default)

as suggested [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69648/gnome-shell-pressing-the-super-key-does-not-work) (comments).