# Window key stops working once a day or so

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Once in a while the Window-key (used as Super-key) stops triggering the usual desktop operations.

Usually it works just fine, but once or twice per day it seems to stop working.

If I open Gnome Tweaks->Keyboard&Mouse->Additional Layout Options and mark and un-mark any checkbox, then the Window key starts working again. That workaround is described in [Gnome shell: pressing the super key does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69648/gnome-shell-pressing-the-super-key-does-not-work)

But the bug reappears daily and it's annoying. Any suggestion what may be the cause of this?

Ubuntu 20.04, Gnome3 desktop. ESC and CapsLock are remapped using dconf but no other keyboard mapping tweaks.

I installed the [terminal emulator kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/index.html) yesterday, and it appears as if each time I start kitty, the Window-key stops working. So it's a way to trigger the fault reliably, but it happened even before I had kitty installed.

When I start kitty I see these messages in journalctl:

```
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Sep 09 08:40:18 dannas--dell-xp-15 gnome-shell[8127]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
```

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard 
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="se"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

This command is the same whether I run it when the Windows keys works or when it doesn't work.

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['caps:swapescape']
```

---

When the Windows key is not working and I run xev and press the key I get this output:

```
$ xev
...
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x5f5, subw 0x0, time 8173867, (165,-14), root:(2113,44),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x5f5, subw 0x0, time 8173995, (165,-14), root:(2113,44),
    state 0x4, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

When the Windows key is working I get:

```
$ xev
...
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967169 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyNonlinear

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyNonlinear

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

---

From [A simple Humble but comprehensive guide to xkb for Linux](https://medium.com/@damko/a-simple-humble-but-comprehensive-guide-to-xkb-for-linux-6f1ad5e13450) I learned a bit more about the xkb system.
When the Windows key is working I see:

```
$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     se,us
variant:    ,
options:    caps:swapescape
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+se+us:2+inet(evdev)+capslock(swapescape)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+se+us:2+inet(evdev)+capslock(swapescape)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

When the Windows key is not working, I see that altwin(ctrl_win), capslock(swapescape) and terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp) are enabled.

```
$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     se,us
variant:    ,
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,altwin:ctrl_win,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,caps:swapescape
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+se+us:2+inet(evdev)+altwin(ctrl_win)+capslock(swapescape)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+se+us:2+inet(evdev)+altwin(ctrl_win)+capslock(swapescape)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

In the past I had altwin(ctrl_win) and terminate(ctlr_alt_bksp) enabled but not anymore. How can I find where these settings are still lingering? I believe I originally set them using Gnome Tweak tool.

Comment: Have you tried to simply reboot?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Rebooting helps, as does tooggling any setting in Gnome Tweaks. So I have a workaround, but the problem keeps reappearing. Now that I've seen that setxkbmap does report altwin(ctrl_win) set I guess I just need to figure out where that setting originates from. Do gnome rely on something else besides /usr/share/X11/xkb? This article suggests that's the case: https://medium.com/@damko/a-simple-humble-but-comprehensive-guide-to-xkb-for-linux-6f1ad5e13450

Comment: I'm lost, sorry. The behavior indicates that you have some kind of personal configuration somewhere which you have forgot about.